# Show used space rather than remaining space in explorer

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7's My Computer window, it shows remaining space on drives, with a progress bar.
Is there some way to get it to show the used space instead?

Comment: Right-click the hard disk. The information you need is on the device properties.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I wanted to have it next to the icon.  Is there a registry key known to change it?  I wouldn't go so far as to install any third-party (or first-party, for that matter) software to fix this, however.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going for "57.6 GB used of 70 GB".  I'm pretty sure it used to be like that in previous versions of Windows.

Comment: 70 GB - 57.6 GB = used space

Comment: It does, but I just like the convenience of seeing it right there.  I get a better at-a-glance perception of the used/available space better that way.

Comment: btw in Windows XP the information displayed is the same. No used space at a glance.

Comment: I think you should start a bounty, to make the question more visible. I wish I knew the answer. :)

Comment: @CorporateGeek, stairmast0r only has 26 rep and the minimum bounty is 50. Of course with 499, you could do it for them...

Answer (score 4):

Simply putting it, no, you can't change the information being presented there.

It was designed like that, and the computer user as no control over the information presented at that specific location.

You can however see that information on the same window activating at least one of the following two options:

### 1)

You can see that information by activating `Percent Full`:

1. Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to open the `view` menu
2. Click on the `Choose details...` item
3. You will see that `Percent Full` is one of the available items, Tick it.

This will activate the `Percent Full` that shows a nice graphical representation as a bar, that will be shown both in the Details and Tiles view.

**Note:** this won't be shown for removable media drives.

---

### 2)

Also, you can click over a drive and observe the `Preview pane`, that shows you the "Space Used" graphical representation as a bar for the selected drive.

If you don't have the `Preview pane` activated, you can access the `organize` menu and go over the `layout` item to activate this panel.

Comment: *> Simply putting it, no, you can't change the information being presented there.*   Sure you can; some of the alternate shells changes and adds information in lots of places to Explorer. Unfortunately that’s not one of them; yet…

Comment: *> You can see that information by activating Percent Full*   That’s not numbers, so it’s of little (not zero, but little) use.     *> Also, you can click over a drive and observe the Preview pane, that shows you the "Space Used" graphical representation as a bar for the selected drive*   That’s just the same as the bar in the list, only less convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, a numeric representation of the total used space on a drive is not currently (ever?) possible with Windows Explorer as it stands.

The ClassicShell extension changes many aspects of Explorer to be more like they were in XP (which also did not show the used-space). One of the most popular features is to show the total size of selected/all items in a folder in the status bar. Sadly, ClassicShell does not currently show used space in the status bar, but the project is actively developed, so you could always request that feature at its [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=290975&atid=1230791) or [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45430/Classic-Shell) sites.

Another option is to try [some other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows) [alternate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45430/Classic-Shell) [shells](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/alternatives.html). None of the on since there’s a good chance that at least one of them incorporates this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly no one asked for a console solution, but the [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) command `df -BG` gives a nice summary for all the drives, with capacity, used, free, percent-used.

```
C:\Users\Bob>df -BG
Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
C:/cygwin64         100G   87G       14G  87% /
D:                  316G  266G       51G  84% /cygdrive/d
E:                  932G  920G       13G  99% /cygdrive/e
F:                    5G    5G        0G 100% /cygdrive/f
L:                  932G  184G      748G  20% /cygdrive/l
W:                    1G    1G        1G   4% /cygdrive/w
```

`-BG` means block size in Gigabytes. Alternatives: `1` `K` `M` `G` `T`. Oh sweet consistency.